# How can I retrieve the first N items from a TensorFlow batch dataset, and not an iterator that reevaluates to different items?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to retrieve the first N items from a BatchDataSet.  I have tried a number of different ways to do this, and they all retrieve *different* items when reevaluated.  However I would like to retrieve N actual items, not an iterator that will continue to retrieve new items.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Images", 
    validation_split=0.2,
    seed=123,
    subset="training")

# Attempt to retrieve 9 items
test_ds = ds.take(9)

# Plot the 9 items and their labels
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for images, labels in test_ds:
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

#
# AGAIN, plot the 9 items and their labels
# NOTE: This will show 9 different images, and my expectation is 
# that it should show the same images as above.
# 
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for images, labels in test_ds:
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over a `tf.data.Dataset` will trigger shuffling every time. You could set `shuffle` to `False` to get deterministic results:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(64, 64),
  batch_size=1,
  shuffle=False)

# Attempt to retrieve 9 items
test_ds = ds.take(9)

class_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
# Plot the 9 items and their labels
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_ds):
  ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
  plt.imshow(images[0, ...].numpy().astype("uint8"))
  plt.title(class_names[labels.numpy()[0]])
  plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_ds):
  ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
  plt.imshow(images[0, ...].numpy().astype("uint8"))
  plt.title(class_names[labels.numpy()[0]])
  plt.axis("off")
```

[image]
[image]

If you are interested in other data samples, you can just use the methods `tf.data.Dataset.skip` and `tf.data.Dataset.take`.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I failed to realize that.  Are there downsides to `shuffle` not being set during training and prediction?

Comment: There are definitely downsides to not shuffling during training. During inference, it really depends what you want to do with your predictions.